# Is the Riemannian distance function Lipschitz on a hypersurface?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ of dimenion $n$.

Is it true that there exists a constant $C$ such that 
$$d(x,y) \leq C|x-y|$$
for all $x, y \in M$? Here $d$ is the Riemannian distance function and $|\cdot|$ is the usual norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

I think it is trivially true that $|x-y| \leq d(x,y)$ since the straight line minimises the distance between two points. But the reverse, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the function 
$$
f(x,y) := \begin{cases} \frac{d(x,y)}{|x-y|} & \text{ if } x \ne y \\
 1 & \text{ if } x=y
\end{cases}
$$
for $(x,y) \in M \times M$. Then $f$ is continuous on a compact set, so it has a maximum which works as $C$ in your question.

Comment: Thanks. So is the point that this works since $d$ is continuous? It has nothing to do with the Riemannian distance function.

Comment: Continuity and compactness plus the fact that it works locally, i.e., that the quotient has a limit as $x \to y$.